# Find differences between two matrix list

Tags: python, list

I found pretty much answers getting difference between 2 lists but couldn't able to find matrix lists.

I have 2 lists like below and I want to get the members which **exist in "list1's first indice" and not exist in "list2's first indice"**

I want to compare only the first indices of the list members and find the difference.

```
list1 = [(12, 'Text1'), (123, 'Text2'), (22, 'Text3')]
list2 = [('22', 'company1'), ('232', 'company2'), ('233', 'company3')]
```

(Not sure why list2's first indices has '' characters, couldn't able to remove it but I think still can be comparable.)

I'm using the code below but it takes hours(both indices has ~5000 members).

Is there any other way to calculate&find fastly?

```
notExist = []
for i,j in list1:
    for x,y in list2:
        if i == x:
            try:
                notExist.remove((i,j))
            except:
                print("Not Exist")
            break
        else:
            if i not in notExist:
                notExist.append((i,j))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both keys lists to sets and use `-` to find the difference:

```
>>> list1 = [(12, 'Text1'), (123, 'Text2'), (22, 'Text3')]
>>> list2 = [('22', 'company1'), ('232', 'company2'), ('233', 'company3')]

>>> s1 = set(x for x, _ in list1)
>>> s2 = set(int(x) for x, _ in list2)

>>> s1 - s2
{123, 12}
>>> s2 - s1
{232, 233}
```

Comment: It throws "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'" error. I deleted to "int" convertion, results are not seen ok. By the way after I found the differences, I need to get second indices too, like "company1"